# CSS: Keep a child (img) properly aligned over a background (img)

Tags: css, image, alignment, scaling

Say I have a small transparent gif I want to align and scale over an image that can scale as the browser changes size. You might have guessed that yes, I want a seamless little animation over photograph such that a small portion of the photo seems to be animated.

Is this just too difficult for pure CSS? I'm already starting to do it in js, just seems complicated with CSS. So while I move on and do it with code, anyone have a funky CSS methodology by chance?

Tried something like this but for some reason the floater image scales with the browser (visible) percent, not the parent div containing the bg image.

```
   <div id="bg-image">
        <div class="bg-container">
            <img class="photo" src="../images/bg_artist.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img class="floater" src="../images/twitter.png"  alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

just pretend i want the child image to show in the lower right:

```
#bg-image .container 
{
    width:102%;
    margin-left:-10px;
}


#bg-image .photo 
{
    width:102%;
    margin-left:-10px;
}

#bg-image .floater {
    position:fixed; 
    left:90%;
    top:90%;
}
```

Well, after futzing around, the js solution is pretty simple:

```
var floater = document.getElementById("floater");
var photo = document.getElementById("bg-photo");

floater.style.left = photo.width * .9 +"px";
floater.style.top = photo.height * .5 + "px";
```

Sorry, I'd put it in a jsfiddle, but it's hard since it deals with  the whole browser.

Comment: Could you [show what you've got, that isn't working](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Isn't the parent div scaling with the browser? Then floater scales with the container.If I understood you right, any demo would be appreciated ;)

Comment: alright, try to whip up a fiddle

Comment: Ew. pain in fiddler to really simulate this. Well the parent is scaling with the image. In this case it stretches horizontally and stretches vertically to maintain the aspect ratio. The .container's height is actually taller than the browser. Problem is, my fixed position div is moving up with the browser bottom. I want it to cut-off like the .photo. Lemme see if I can get  a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little unclear what you want the final behavior to be, but [this has the images scaling and staying located in relation to each other](http://jsfiddle.net/p8nkp/3/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="bg-image">
   <img class="photo" src="path/bkgimage.png" alt=""/>
   <img class="floater" src="path/floatimage.png"  alt="" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#bg-image {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}


#bg-image .photo {
    width:100%;
}

#bg-image .floater {
    position:absolute;
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: friggin' weird. It works fine with this css in a test case, but I have some other element or css interfering. Haven't been able to isolate it yet in the application, but I will mark as answered anyway. In my case the body has overflow set to hidden, but I tried that in my test case and it still works...